# Fill a Card widget with a photo in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a circleavatar within a card widget but the image is not displaying as intended, how can I fill the card with the image rather than getting this eyeball effect?

[Card with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn5IH.jpg)

```
[Card(
                          shape: CircleBorder(),
                          elevation: 10.0,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            radius: 75.0,
                            child: ClipOval(
                              child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                                placeholder:
                                    'lib/screens/shared/defaultprofile.png',
                                image: userData.profilephoto,
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using ClipOval class A widget that clips its child using an oval.

By default, inscribes an axis-aligned oval into its layout dimensions and prevents its child from painting outside that oval, but the size and location of the clip oval can be customized using a custom clipper.You can remove it to have your desired view.

```
CircleAvatar(
Backgroundimage: NetworkImage(url)
...
```

Also see hw to [add assets to you flutter app](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)

Comment: removing the clipoval leaves me with a card circle and an overflowing rectangular image https://ibb.co/b74GbQx